# ContentPanes wouldn't show up

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have `TabContainer` with two `ContentPanes` inside

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" data-dojo-props="doLayout:false">
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Foo">
    Foo
  </div>
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Bar">
    Bar
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason when page loads - both tabs are invisible. If I resize the browser - tabs appear.

Same problem on Chrome, FF, IE8+ and Safari.

I've checked the console. For some reason, all elements have height=0, width=0 and display=none.

Comment: This is usually something I see if the TabContainer is created (and its `startup()` is called) when the TabContainer div itself or one of its ascendants has `display: none`, or are otherwise not part of the document flow (e.g. hasn't been inserted into the DOM tree yet). Is that the case in your code?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming `</bar>` is just a typo in your question :)

Comment: If the situation that Frode is describing is true,  then you have to call the widgets .resize() after the hidden parent is shown

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use widget.resize() on dom ready. See comments for details.